# converting a tree-like list to a full-path-list

Tags: scheme, guile

I'm tying to use `file-system-tree` function from 
https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/File-Tree-Walk.html#File-Tree-Walk. In combination with `remove-stat`from the link it results in tree-like list structure, e.g. for

```
test/
├── dir1
├── dir2
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── file1
```

we get `("test" (("dir2" ("file2" "file3")) "dir1" "file1"))`

How to convert that list to list of all full paths? like this
`("test/" "test/file1" "test/dir2" "test/dir2/file3" "test/dir2/file2" "test/dir1")`

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You have to be more specific. What have you tried sofar? Where are you stuck? Please read [ask] and revise your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What we need to do is define a recursive function that iterates over the `car` of the `cdr` of a given list, appending the `car` of the list to string items, and calling itself on another list element, then taking the returned items and appending the `car` of the list on those, too. Here's what that would look like in code:

```
(define (tree->full-path-list tree)
  (flatten (append (list (car tree))
                   (map (lambda (x)
                          (if (list? x)
                              (map (lambda (y)
                                     (string-append (car tree) "/" y))
                                   (tree->full-path-list x))
                              (string-append (car tree) "/" x)))
                        (car (cdr tree))))))
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks, that is exactly what i was looking for, but never managed to use map-on-map-on-recursion

Comment: Good to hear that, @sciamano! Actually, speaking of map-on-map, I would rather have found a way to not have to nest two very similar `map`s. In fact, if anyone knows a good way to eliminate this, I would very much like to know.

Comment: @ChristopherDumas Maybe have a look at my answer, which avoids `map` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late to the party but I think this could be done in a much easier (and probably faster) way than the accepted solution, using a classical named-let:

```
(define (path-append part1 part2)
  ;; concatenate paths (lazy man's version)
  (if (non-empty-string? part1)
      (string-append part1 "/" part2)
      part2))

(define (f lst)
  (reverse 
   (let loop ((lst lst) (path "") (res null))
     (if (null? lst)
         res
         (let ((c (car lst)))
           (loop (cdr lst)
                 path
                 (if (list? c)
                     (loop c (car res) res) ; this recurses into sub-lists
                     (cons (path-append path c) res))))))))
```

Not perfect, but close:

```
> (f '("test" (("dir2" ("file2" "file3")) "dir1" "file1")))
'("test" "test/dir2" "test/dir2/file2" "test/dir2/file3" "test/dir1" "test/file1")
```